# payload android. Meterpreter connection issue on samsung s7 edge

Tags: android, metasploit

Hello I have 2 samsung s7 edge the both have the same android version and base band.
 On the first no problem, i'm able to take the control using reverse_tcp or http. 
On the second the payload doesn't work properly. After a short time the connection close and display "Meterpreter session 1 is not valid and will be closed". Then when I try some command like sysinfo etc... A message appear "not valid command" and when I typing "help" the Android commands doesn't appear, only some commands like UUID etc...
Of course I uninstall the payload from the first S7 edge before to try on the second. I use metasploit v4.14.27.
On the second S7 edge there is no antivirus or firewall. 
I trying since fews days without good result. 
If you could help me please.
Thanks in advance.